# Python GTK 3 Popover off window?

Tags: python, gtk3

So basically I have a window thats just a vertical list of buttons. I want to create a dropdown menu that goes off to the side without changing the size of the window. I am trying to do this with popover, but now I have the problem where my popover gets cut off by the window. Is there a way I can make it bleed past the window boundaries?

Comment: Hey, don't know the answer to your question. Just wanted to tell you that GTK 3 is not PyGTK, but PyGObject. So if you change that tag you may get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popovers don't go wider than the parent window. You could have a try at a [GtkMenu](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html). They are allowed to go wider than the window, up to the width of the monitor.